# Control over buffer of mp3 stream

Tags: javascript, audio, streaming, html5-audio, audio-streaming

Currently I'm some streams urls (like [this example](http://radio.talksport.com/stream?awparams=platform:ts-tunein;lang:en&aw_0_1st.playerid=RadioTime&aw_0_1st.skey=1572173094&aw_0_1st.platform=tunein)) which i'm playing normally as `new Audio()`. Like the code bellow:

```js
const audio = new Audio();
audio.src = 'http://radio.talksport.com/stream?awparams=platform:ts-tunein;lang:en&aw_0_1st.playerid=RadioTime&aw_0_1st.skey=1572173094&aw_0_1st.platform=tunein';
audio.load();
audio.play();
```

But I'm struggling to add some custom buffer on the given stream, like set a buffer of 2 min. Is possible to do with streaming?

Answer (score 0):

This is a live stream, so no, you cannot set a buffer of 2 minutes.

(Unless of course you want to have the user wait 2 minutes before playing anything back.)